# Restoring and rendering annotations in pdf.js

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I am using [pdf.js viewer](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html). I am able to create annotations, retrieve them and store them as json.

To get annotations from console, I use this;

```
PDFViewerApplication.pdfDocument._transport.annotationStorage.getAll();
```

I am also able to set default options such as `'defaultUrl'`

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {                
    PDFViewerApplicationOptions.set('defaultUrl', 'compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf');
});
```

My question is, how do you restore and render prior annotations from the json file on reload?

I have tried this but it does work?

```
PDFViewerApplication.pdfDocument._transport.annotationStorage.setAll();
```

Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Phemelo Khetho, did you ever work out how to do this? I'm struggling with the same issue - I'm not sure how to restore + render annotations to a PDF document.

Comment: @user2444499 I never found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to load a document has annotations, I think pdf.js will show annotations in PDF file if you set correct annotationMode option.

Comment: Do you have a working example or code snippet to show how's it's done?

Comment: I confirmed the [official default viewer](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html) suport show annotations.